# How to create a Bundle in a Unit test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, android-testing

I want to test a method that deals with [Bundles](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html). I'm unable to create a (non-null) Bundle object in the test environment, though.

Given the following code:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", "value");
boolean containsKey = bundle.containsKey("key");
```

`containsKey` is `true` if the code is executed in the application context, but `false` if executed in a unit test.

[image: Service Context]

[image: Test Context]

I can't figure out why that's the case and how to create a Bundle for my tests.

Comment: Have you tried a mocking framework to create a Bundle? It is strange it would be null, though

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If your build script contains something like this:

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

then it's a cause why your test doesn't fail even if your don't specify a mock for Bundle class.

There are a few options to deal with this problem:

1. Use [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) mocking framework to mock a Bundle class. Unfortunately, you have to write a lot of boilerplate code by yourself. For example you can use this method to mock a bundle object, so it will return you the right values by **getString** method:

   ```
    @NonNull
    private Bundle mockBundle() {
          final Map<String, String> fakeBundle = new HashMap<>();
          Bundle bundle = mock(Bundle.class);
          doAnswer(new Answer() {
          @Override
          public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();
                String key = ((String) arguments[0]);
                String value = ((String) arguments[1]);
                fakeBundle.put(key, value);
                return null;
          }
          }).when(bundle).putString(anyString(), anyString());
          when(bundle.get(anyString())).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
                 @Override
                 public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                      Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();
                      String key = ((String) arguments[0]);
                      return fakeBundle.get(key);
                  }
          });
          return bundle;
     }
   ```
2. Use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) framework that provides some kind of shadow classes for your unit tests. This allows you to use Android specific classes in unit testing and they will act properly. By using that framework your unit test will act properly almost without any changes from your side.
3. The most undesirable by you, I guess, but well, it's eligible. You can make your test functional and run it on your android device or emulator. I **do not recommend** that way because of speed. Before executing tests you have to build a test apk, install it and run. This is super slow if you're going to do TDD.

Comment: I came here because I was too lazy to write that mock myself. :)

Comment: For completeness, I also had to add `when(bundle.keySet()).then(new Answer<Set<String>>() {

            @Override
            public Set<String> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                return fakeBundle.keySet();
            }
        });` in case you want to test something that iterates over the bundle's key set.

Comment: Hi! I didn't find any library or GH for this, so I've just created this small repo to help other people who might need it, inspired by your answer (@andrei_zaitcev). 

It's this one: https://github.com/LluisFelip/MockBundle

It's my first time making a public contribution to GH so if anyone has some suggestion on how to improve it or something, I'd be more than happy to know :)

Comment: There is a complete and usable example of BundleMock file in Java here:
https://github.com/konmik/nucleus/blob/master/nucleus-test-kit/src/main/java/mocks/BundleMock.java
Just copy the file into your test folder and use it. It works.

Comment: @BorisGitlin Post this as an answer. I will upvote it.

Comment: @Shishir Shetty - Done

Answer (score 2):

With Mockito you can do:

```
Bundle mockBundle = Mockito.mock(Bundle.class);
Mockito.when(mockBundle.containsKey("key")).thenReturn(true);
```

*containsKey* will now be true in the class you are testing.

Some additional info on when().  When you wrap a mocked object method call with when(), it will skip calling the actual implementation of that method and immediately return the value provided in the thenReturn() part.  This is a lifesaver when writing certain unit tests because it can be nightmarish once a method calls down into it's rabbit holes.

This is the best way I've found for setting up the path for getting to the code you actually want to test.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Mockito:

```
Bundle extras = mock(Bundle.class);
```

And since I didn't need to test a lot of parameters that passed within bundle, i mocked calls to them like this:

```
private void stubParameterNameExtras(Bundle extras, boolean value) {
    when(extras.getBoolean(KEY, false)).thenReturn(value);
}
```

Suggestion to the team I made was to replace Bundle usage with Java analog.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using Kotlin and `mockk`, modeled after [`bundleOf`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/os/package-summary#bundleOf(kotlin.Pair))

```
private fun mockBundleOf(vararg pairs: Pair<String, Any?>): Bundle {
    val bundle = mockk<Bundle>()

    for ((key, value) in pairs) {
        when (value) {
            is Boolean -> every { bundle.getBoolean(key) } returns value
            is Byte -> every { bundle.getByte(key) } returns value
            is Char -> every { bundle.getChar(key) } returns value
            is Double -> every { bundle.getDouble(key) } returns value
            is Float -> every { bundle.getFloat(key) } returns value
            is Int -> every { bundle.getInt(key) } returns value
            is Long -> every { bundle.getLong(key) } returns value
            is Short -> every { bundle.getShort(key) } returns value
            is String -> every { bundle.getString(key) } returns value
            else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException("Type is not supported.")
        }
    }

    return bundle
}
```